# Kindle Android - Refresh a book cover?

Tags: images, ebook-reader, kindle-for-android

I use the Kindle app for Android. I had 'bought' one of the classic titles which they have - *War and Peace*, which, like many of the classics, had no cover image.

They have since updated the title on the Kindle store with a picture for the cover. I would like to update the title on my device so that it shows the cover art. How can I do this?

I tried "deleting" the title (it then goes to "archived items") and then redownloading it but this did not work. I also checked in *Quick App Clean Cache* to see if there was a cache I could clean, but Kindle is not listed. I also tried doing a 'sync' from within Kindle. None of these steps has helped.

My device is a Samsung Galaxy S Captivate, running Eclair yet (I think I'm getting my Froyo sometime this month).

If possible, I would certainly prefer to do this in such a way as to not lose my positions in the books I'm reading.

Comment: Did you try restarting the device without all the extra stuff? I have no idea why this would work, but I can confirm it did in my case, and has been recommended by the guys at [StoryBundle](http://storybundle.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You could try deleting the app cache. Go to Settings > Applications > Manage Applications and find the Kindle app. Click on it and then hit the button that says "Clear Data". This will clear cache and start you off at square one again with the app. Then see what happens.

Comment: Hmm, I don't seem to have a "Delete Data" button; there's one that says "Clear cache", but it is disabled. It does show it as using 384KB of data though. Is the "Delete Data" button a Froyo thing? I haven't received the Froyo update yet.

Comment: You don't have a button that says "Clear Data"? Maybe it is a Froyo thing. You could try clearing the cache, uninstalling the app, reboot the phone, and then try reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

I recently "bought" a selection of the classic, free books for Kindle a few days ago. On Amazon (UK)'s webpage they were showing with full colour book covers, when they downloaded to my Android's Kindle app a few minutes later they came down with blank, default covers.

Have tried a lot of playing with it too, and can't see a way to get the covers for these books to download. Maybe they just don't send covers for free books to the Android app?

Comment: Nah, that's not it. I have numerous free books which brought down their cover art... e.g. **Bram Stoker's Dracula**, the **Star Wars: Lost Tribe of the Sith** series and **Alice's Adventures in Wonderland**. Once I'm done with the book I'm currently reading, I'll have to try doing an all-out uninstall/reinstall and see if that updates the ones that didn't get their covers. *sigh*